# How to define ManyToManyField to retrieve only distinct objects by default?

Tags: django

```
class UserProfile(Model):
    base = OneToOneField(User)
    commented_articles = ManyToManyField('Article', through='Comment')
```

In above case, how can I somehow hack the related manager `commented_articles` to filter the articles with `distinct()` method by default?

I know I can get the distinct articles by calling `distinct()` method like:

```
>>> u = UserProfile.objects.first()
>>> u.commented_articles.distinct()
```

But I want the related manager `commented_articles` itself to contain `distinct()` query by default, while implementation take the place in the model's definition.

Is there any nice way to make related manager to return distinct-filtered queryset by default?

Comment: The question is, why do you even store values several times? Is this behavior required? If it is, you can write a [qustom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#manager-types) with `use_for_related_fields = True`.

Comment: `use_for_related_fields` does not work with M2M fields (at least yet), please see [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14891)1

Answer (score 0):

`distinct()` would be redundant had you not specified a custom `through` parameter; though I can certainly see why you did that.  Why don't you just make commented_articles a cached property that return the queryset you really want, e.g.:

```
class UserProfile(Model)
    ...
    @cached_property
    def commented_articles(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(comment__userprofile=self).distinct()
```

`ManyToManyFields` are not that useful if you need to store anything but the relation in their `through` model.  The Django ORM will provide you with the relations anyway.